# When to use typedef in closure?

Tags: javascript, types, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

I have been confused for a long time regarding the following code snippet:

```
/**
 * Pair of width and height.
 * @param {string} width
 * @param {string} height
 * @constructor
 * @struct
 */
var Pair = function(width, height) {
  /** @type {string} */
  this.key = key;
  /** @type {string} */
  this.value = value;
};
```

**vs**

```
/**
 * @typedef {{width: string, height: string}}
 */
var Pair;
```

Basically I need to create a new type and highly confused about which one to use when?

Comment: I think a good answer should cover the differences between typedef, record and interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which one to use when?

This is to some extent a matter of personal preference and coding style.  Closure Compiler leans more towards the *pseudoclassical inheritance pattern* found in Java with classes, interfaces, methods, etc. which is different to other approaches. See [Inheritance Patterns in JavaScript](http://bolinfest.com/javascript/inheritance.php) by Michael Bolin.

See also [Annotating JavaScript for the Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler) which has the most concise definitions of the various tags.

For myself, I use the pseudoclassical inheritance pattern.  Therefore 99% of the time I am defining classes with `@constructor` which are meant to be used with the `new` keyword.  These classes are also marked with `@struct` so they have a fixed set of properties and methods.  Around 80% of my classes state that they `@implement` an `@interface` because that allows me to use the interface types and not be tied to a particular class implementation.

Occasionally I will use `@typedef` to define an object that has some minimal set of properties.  For me, this type of object usually has no functions defined on it, it is merely a way to aggregate some properties.

Here's an example from my code:

```
/**  A regular expression and the replacement string expression to be used in a
* `String.replace()` command.
* @typedef {{regex: !RegExp, replace: string}}
* @private
*/
Terminal.regexPair;
```

I can use that typedef elsewhere:

```
/** Set of regular expressions to apply to each command.
* @type {!Array.<!Terminal.regexPair>}
* @private
*/
this.regexs_ = [];
```

The advantage is that it is easy to make something of this type:

```
/** Add regular expression and replacement string to be used by `String.replace()`
* for transforming script commands before they are executed.
* @param {!RegExp} regex regular expression for finding a name to transform
* @param {string} replace the replacement string for use with `String.replace()`
*/
Terminal.prototype.addRegex = function(regex, replace) {
  this.regexs_.push({regex:regex, replace:replace});
};
```

Notice that I made an anonymous object with `{regex:regex, replace:replace}` instead of using the `new` operator.  Yet the compiler is checking that this object has the required (minimal) set of properties defined by `Terminal.regexPair`.

But there are many other philosophies about how to write JavaScript code.  And you could certainly define a typedef that requires functions with specified signatures.